# Setting innerHTML vs. setting value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

When you want to use Javascript to change HTML, how do you know when to use either of the following?

```
document.getElementById("randomNumber").value = number;
document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = number;
```

Comment: The best answer to this question is on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1037389/innerhtml-vs-value-when-and-why

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Setting the `value` is normally used for input/form elements. `innerHTML` is normally used for div, span, td and similar elements.

Here is a link showing the use of ID.value:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml

Comment: Saying something is normal is not actual explanation.

Answer (score 15):

`value` is for form elements, `innerHTML` if you want to set the content of any other element.
There's also `innerText` if you want to set the text content (you won't have to escape anything in there, but no HTML works in there)

Comment: Thumbs up for mentioning `innerText`

Answer (score 8):

`value` is generally a property of specific i/o elements such as `input` elements (also including the `type="hidden"`).

elements which are not such as `div, p, a, etc.` generally don't even have the value property and even if a `value` is set, does not affect the final output.

Answer (score 3):

`value` applies only to objects that have the `value` attribute (normally, form controls).

`innerHtml` applies to every object that can contain HTML (divs, spans, but many other and also form controls).

They are not equivalent or replaceable. Depends on what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

`value` represents the value that would be GETed or POSTed for `input` elements. `innerHTML` could change the contents actual elements.

Answer (score 1):

Value is for input

innerHTML for div and span

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late for him but I was also looking for an answer and I think according to Skyrim answer
It is possible to do something like this
Thanks

```js
function enterValue() {
  var childNodes = document.body.childNodes;
  for (x of childNodes) {
    if(x.nodeName=="INPUT"){
      // element is an INPUT html tag
      x.value = "my input value";
    }else{
      // element is anything other than an INPUT
      x.innerHTML  = "my input value";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input name="mInput" />
<div></div>
<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="button" onclick="enterValue()" value="enterValue">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .innerHTML to replace the entire inner body of the element with valid HTML you specify.  A good example of this would be to place a nested div in an already existing div if an event occurs.

Use .value for form elements that request a value, such as a text input.