# insert text into webform using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so i have this bot that i want to create that will simulate user input. the website i am using is WattsApp web. when i type a message into the website it enables a button that allows the message to be sent.

when i run my script it finds the input box (where i would type in manual). it then changes the innerHTML to a test string. it then finds the send button and clicks it.

the problem is that when i change the innerHTML the send button is not enabled. i have been searching for a long time to see why and i can not see a difference between manually typing in text and using a script for it. here is my script:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("input")[1].innerHTML="TestString!!!";
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("icon btn-icon icon-send send-container");
input[0].click();
```

but it get a error when i run the second line because the class "icon btn-icon icon-send send-container" can not be found except if i manual type in text. can anyone help? is there a difference between chaining the inner HTML and typing in text?

Comment: if i also edit the HTML to include a test string, it also does not work

Comment: I suspect that it is listening for an event on the textbox rather than monitoring the value

Comment: to set input value, use `input.value = 'new value'`. innerHTML sets the HTML contents and an input is a self-closing empty element so it can not have any HTML inside.

Comment: Setting the content of an input doesn't trigger onchange effects, it's one of the ways you can see if a user typed something or if a script is trying to bot. You could try manaully triggering the onchange on the input element, but rememebr that it's against the rules of whatsapp, so you could get banned. (according to the first google search)

Comment: As Yoda said, you probably have more code which you're not showing here, which wires to the textbox input's onchange event, and enables the button when onchange occurs.  Since setting the text of a textbox via javascript will not fire the onchange event like normal user input would, onchange is not being fired, and the button is not being enabled.

Comment: I am making a bot that will get updates from GIT and send them to all the registed users as a notification. its for a group project for college. As it will not be used for anything else i did not think it would be a problem

Comment: i have the inspect tab open. when i type in the input box it shows me what has been changed. and there is nothing else that happends

Comment: Try manually triggering the onchange event, assuming you got the correct input element selected. If you don't have the correct input element, use one of the answers below, who don't address the onchange issue. ;) You could also check if the button has the disabled attribute. maybe you can undisable it directly as well by using setAttribute() on it.

Comment: the image i uploaded shows what i can see that changes when i manually type in text

Answer (score 0):

icon,  btn-icon, icon-send , and send-container are all specific class names of the element you are selecting. Use one of them instead like below.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("icon");
```

or

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-icon");
```

or

```
 var input = document.getElementsByClassName("icon-send");
```

continues ...based on your need

Comment: i added a second image that shows the class name. it is all of them as far as i can tell. the image is at the bottom of the question

Comment: I saw that. the rule is  when you have a space between the name, it will no longer going to serve as one name. for instance if you have class ="a b", this doesn't mean the class name is "a b", rather it means the the element associated with that class can be referred by "a" or "b", hence to select that element you can use document.getElementsByClassName("a") or document.getElementsByClassName("b"). as two elements can have the same class names, if you want a specific class name you can add another name with in the quote after space for instance class ="a b c"..

Answer (score 0):

Ur class name is wrong use only send-container

Answer (score 0):

When trying to set the value of inputs, you need to set the value

Given: `<input id="myTextBox" />`

SetValue: `document.getElementById('myTextBox').value = 'MyInput';`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823498/setting-innerhtml-vs-setting-value-with-javascript)