# HTML code Not showing Output

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing a Website that has to use session Storage storage. I am able to store the value and also view it in the Storage section of my browser, however when I try to retrieve it nothing happens. My full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<style>
.navbar 
{
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar a 
{
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown 
{
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 16px;    
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
display: block;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
width: 30%;
}
</style>
<body>
<form  method="POST">   
<div class="navbar">
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#news">Shopping Cart</a>
<a href="#news">Change Details</a>
<div align="center">
<input type="text" name="searchspace" placeholder="Search">
<input type="submit" value="search" name="searchbutton" >
<p id="nametag">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
<ul>
<li>Shampoo</li>
<li>Soap</li>
<li>Conditioner</li>
</ul>
<table align="left">
<?php
require ('sql_connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['searchbutton']))
{
if($_POST['searchspace'])
{
    $look=mysql_escape_string($_POST['searchspace']);
    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_table` WHERE (name like'%$look%' or description like '%$look%')");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
     {


        echo "<tr><td>{$row['name']} by {$row['brand']}</td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td>{$row['description']}</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>{$row['price']}</td></tr>";
      echo "<tr><td><input type=submit value= 'add to cart' id={$row['product_id']}></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td></br></td></tr>";

      }

    }
    else
    {
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('No product Found')
            </SCRIPT>");

    }
}
}


exit();
?>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('nametag').innerHTML = "See this works.";
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps in helping you figure out where my error is.

Comment: As far as I know, the `<p>` tag doesn't have a value attribute, you should use `innerHTML` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting innerHTML vs. setting value with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823498/setting-innerhtml-vs-setting-value-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `innerHTML` instead of `value`

```js
document.getElementById('nametag').innerHTML = "See this works."; //ORIGINAL CODE: sessionStorage.getItem('user');
```

```html
<p id="nametag">Hello</p>
```

Comment: Good answer, depends however on what you want to do. You can also use `textContent` to only change the text.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the DOM properties of `textContent`, never use of it before due to the support is from IE 9 (but who use IE these days haha)

Comment: Didnt display "See this works." can u suggest another tag for displaying this

Comment: Can you let us know if you are trying with any other codes? This should work on most of the cases unless the element you selecting doesn't exists or doesn't have the properties of `innerHTML`