# Combining strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with Javascript and I created a simple HTML page with two fields, a button, and another field that should be the combination of the first two fields.

However, my Javascript is not working. Here are my files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>My First Web Page</h2>
  <p id="first">My First Paragraph.</p>
  <p id="second">My Second Paragraph.</p>
  <input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Combine" />
  <p id="third">Concatenate first and second.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the Javascript

```
myFunction(){
  var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var second = document.getElementById("second").value;

  var third = first + " " + second;
  document.getElementById("third").value = third;

}
```

Alternatively, I'm testing it on [this](https://codepen.io/adhysatya/pen/XPXzvB) Codepen template

Comment: Paragraphs don't have the `value` attribute. Form elements do

Comment: In your codepen your js has a syntax error - click the error icon to see it

Comment: Your syntax for declaring a function is incorrect, it should be `function myFunction() {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `innerText` instead of `value`.  And declare function correctly.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var first = document.getElementById("first").innerText;
  var second = document.getElementById("second").innerText;
  var third = first + " " + second;
  document.getElementById("third").innerText = third;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>My First Web Page</h2>
  <p id="first">My First Paragraph.</p>
  <p id="second">My Second Paragraph.</p>
  <input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Combine" />
  <p id="third">Concatenate first and second.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must declare it as function. And value is not the right property to modify, but you can use 'innerHTML' or example. Here is the updated, working JS.

```
function myFunction(){
    var first = document.getElementById("first").innerHTML;
    var second = document.getElementById("second").innerHTML;
    var third = first + " " + second;
    document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = third;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `textContent` instead:

```
function myFunction(){
  var first = document.getElementById("first").textContent;
  var second = document.getElementById("second").textContent;

  var third = first + " " + second;
  document.getElementById("third").textContent = third;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are setting the value of the paragraph and not the html.

What you should do is use innerHTML instead of value.

[Here is a stackoverflow discussion about the difference between value and innerHTML:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823498/setting-innerhtml-vs-setting-value-with-javascript)