# Get dynamical span value to text box is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I want to assign the dynamical span value to my text box, I have tried below code, why this is not working can some one help me.

```
<style name="question.after" wrap="ready"><![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {  
    document.getElementById("ans1103.0.4").value=document.getElementById('span1103.0').innerHTML;
});
]]></style>
```

Comment: You've put your JS code in a `<style>` tag. It needs to go in a `<script>` tag

Comment: this also not working<script>
  $ (document).ready(function() { 
                  setInterval(function(){        
                                 document.getElementById("ans1103.0.31").value=document.getElementById("span1103.0").innerHTML;     
                  },1)
 });
</script>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan could you pls help me above code

Comment: Without seeing the relevant HTML we can't help any further

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823498/setting-innerhtml-vs-setting-value-with-javascript