# How to print value of button to input box onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, calculator

Here the button '1' is displaying value "1" in <!p> tag on clicking but the second button '2' is not displaying value "2" in the input box.Though both the functions are same.

```js
//Working
function one1() {
  onee = document.getElementById("b1").value;
  document.getElementById("ptag").innerHTML += "1";
}
//Not Working
function one2() {
  twoo = document.getElementById("b2").value;
  document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "1";
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="mydiv"><br>
<button id="b1" value="1" onclick="one1()">1</button>
<button id="b2" value="2" onclick="one2()">2</button>
<br>
<p id="ptag">This is p tag</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second function is targeting an input, not a paragraph, so `innerHTML` isn't what you want. You want `value` instead

```js
//Working
function one1() {
  onee = document.getElementById("b1").value;
  document.getElementById("ptag").innerHTML += "1";
}
//Not Working
function one2() {
  twoo = document.getElementById("b2").value;
  document.getElementById("mydiv").value += "1";
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="mydiv"><br>
<button id="b1" value="1" onclick="one1()">1</button>
<button id="b2" value="2" onclick="one2()">2</button>
<br>
<p id="ptag">This is p tag</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

InnerHtml property will not work in case of input elements. Input elements are not like your paragraph element or any other elements that can contain any other html element.

What to do then?
Input elements have value property by which you can get and set values to input elements.
document.getElementById("mydiv").value += "1"; will do the job for you.

Also see - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

Answer (score 0):

Input type controls dont use innerHtml to set or get value, you need to access the value property of the control.

[innerhtml vs value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823498/setting-innerhtml-vs-setting-value-with-javascript)