# JavaScript delete sentences add new default sentences with regex

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm learning java script.
I am currently trying to figure out the regex.
I want to try the option when I enter something in the text area field, to automatically click on the button to delete the text entered in the field and print the regex text some that will be the default, and to replace HTML entities with their visual display: & amp; in &, & nbsp; with a space, & quot; with quotation marks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="demo" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50">

  </textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="btnText" onclick="tipka()">click</button>
<script>
function tipka(){
let str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
let res = str.replace(/abc/g, "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand question there should be `document.getElementById("demo").value`   not   `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="demo" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50">

  </textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="btnText" onclick="tipka()">click</button>
<script>
function tipka(){
let str = document.getElementById("demo").value; 

let res = str.replace(/abc/g, "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.");
document.getElementById("demo").value= res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know what to get: when I write text in textarea to automatically regex convert to text defined as its constant

Comment: Can you comment an example?  When you write some  sentenses  which contains string  'abc'   it change  by the default text which is  written  in regex

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires a few changes :

1. Inside `tipka`, the function should read the `value` of the `textarea` instead of the `innerHTML`.
2. Similarly, while replacing the text, set the `value` of the `textfield` instead of `innerHTML`.

See [Setting innerHTML vs. setting value with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823498/setting-innerhtml-vs-setting-value-with-javascript)

Here's the snippet working with the suggested changes :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <textarea id="demo" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50">
  </textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="btnText" onclick="tipka()">click</button>

  <script>
    function tipka() {
      let str = document.getElementById("demo").value;
      let res = str.replace(/abc/g, "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.");
      document.getElementById("demo").value = res;
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```